# canvas.toDataURL don't respect quality passed

Tags: image, canvas, compression, png, jpeg

I playing with canvas object and i want to export image from canvas and compress it on client side.
`canvas` object have `toDataUrl()` method that accept quality range.

I try:

```
 console.log("1.0 ratio bytes:" + canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0).length);
 console.log("0.1 ratio bytes:" + canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 0.1).length);
```

Both lines produce same output, also when i upload result to server the file size is the same for both also. What is wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: the `encoderOptions` parameter only works for `image/jpeg` and  `image/webp`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL#Parameters `image/png` quality is always 1.

Comment: Thanks, found it a second ago -) So there is no way to comress .png's on client side?

Comment: not in a native way no... You could probably gzip it. Also, transforming it to a blob will save 30% of data transfered, But what is your use case?

Comment: Just need to omptimize image sizes on admin site while uploading. The formats could be .jpeg, .png, .gif.

Comment: then choose jpeg if transparency is not needed, or scale the image down.

Comment: `image/jpeg` with lower quality setting will give you small file size. You might also check out [this](https://github.com/epistemex/png-crush) png compression script by Stackoverflow member k3n.